# Driver for AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet

Tags: drivers, kernel-modules, hardware, ethernet, usb-device

I have the following Ethernet to USB-C adapter:

```
$ lsusb | grep Ethernet
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0b95:1790 ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet
```

Currently it is not working when plugged into the USB-C port, in `dmesg` I get:

```
[23552.344134] ax88179_178a 2-1:2.1 eth1: Failed to read reg index 0x0000: -32
```

(However, it works on a different machine, but the error is still shown, and the transfer rate seems limited.)

I am wondering if I have the correct driver installed. I've seen that [`axge`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/man4/axge.4freebsd.html) seems to be the correct driver, but it does not show up in `lsmod`.

**What is the correct driver to use for AX88179, how to check if it is installed, and how to install it otherwise?**

I am currently using Linux Mint 20.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`axge`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/man4/axge.4freebsd.html) driver you linked is for the FreeBSD version of Ubuntu.

The corresponding Linux driver seems to be named `ax88179_178a`. It should be included in the standard kernels of all modern distributions, as the copyright marking in the source code is from year 2013. [Here it is in kernel version 4.9.318, the oldest kernel currently in long-term support by the kernel developers.](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/drivers/net/usb/ax88179_178a.c?h=v4.9.318)